# Copiar datos de una tabla a otra

Tags: mysql

Tengo una base de datos que es un completo desastre y muchas entradas repetidas y tenemos que pasar a un sistema nuevo que no permite duplicados en ciertas cosas...

Como hago para hacer lo siguiente:

**Tabla Clientes:** idcliente nombre documento, etc.

**Tabla Equipo:** id idcliente marca, etc.

Necesito en la tabla Equipo agregar un campo que diga, documento y necesito copiar en la tabla equipos, el numero de documento del cliente según el idcliente corresponda.
Básicamente se me ocurre eliminar el idcliente y reemplazar por el documento ya que arrastramos muchísimas tablas con el idcliente y el único valor que realmente nunca se va a pisar es el numero de documento, y con esto poder limpiar clientes duplicados y poder unificar el resto de las tablas que estén asignados a clientes duplicados sin perder información.

Desde ya muchas gracias.

Intenté algo así pero obviamente no funciona:

```
INSERT INTO equipo
SELECT num_documento FROM cliente
WHERE cliente.idcliente = equipo.idcliente
```

Comment: reemplazar un id por el documento, nunca es una buena idea.. si documento es pk, y de casualidad lo escribieron mal, y se dan cuenta despues, no hay forma de volver atras...

Comment: Y ademas, estas totalmente seguro que documento es unico realmente?

Comment: igual, cual es el problema? de tu pregunta no surge ningun problema...

Comment: Hola, no, la idea es limpiar la base de datos si bien no son muchas entradas, si lo son para hacerlas manualmente, el documento es único en nuestra base de datos (salvo los duplicados) pero a como esta armada actualmente el numero de documento es algo que podemos usar para filtrar muchos de los registros, por eso es que necesito hacer eso de esta manera, luego replicaré ese código para mover el resto de los datos... el problema es que, no me copia el numero de documento a su respectivos equipos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo pude solucionar:

```
UPDATE equipo
INNER JOIN cliente ON equipo.idcliente = cliente.idcliente              
SET cliente.num_documento = equipo.num_documento
```

Tuve que actualizar la tabla EQUIPO uniéndola con la tabla Clientes y comparar el idcliente en ambas tablas y actualizar el num_documento.